# Need SQL query in Oracle to fetch last name from the string separated by comma

Tags: sql, oracle

```
name
------
[pratik]
[Ishaan,llc,ltd]
[sundaar,j]
[sid,h]

output should be like:
name                last_name
------              ---------
[pratik]            null
[Ishaan,llc,ltd]    ltd
[sundaar,j]         j
[sid,h]             h
```

> is there any way by which we can achieve the above in Oracle SQL

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select replace(replace(regexp_substr(name, ',([^,]+)\]$'), ',', ''), ']', '') as last_name
```

Or using `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(name, '^(.*,|[\[a-zA-Z]+)([^,]*)\]$', '\2')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d3db10440f375b9ce7c8fa941fbaf890) is the db<>fiddle.

I should note that storing multiple values in a string is a bad idea.  SQL and Oracle have many better solutions than overloading the definition of a string.

Comment: Hi Gordin, Thanks for suggestion!!. Tried but it is giving me output as 
last_name
----------

,
,
,

Comment: @SiddheshBerde . . . I fixed the answer and added db<>fiddles.

Comment: None of those works correctly. The first contains `[pratik`, while the second contains `pratik` while **both** of those rows should have returned NULL.

Comment: @SiddheshBerde . . . If fixed both.  Your question is quite clear, but I got in my mind that you wanted `pratik` for the first case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `regexp_substr` with `regexp_count` oe `instr` to achieve the desired result as following:

```
Select case when regexp_count(name, ',') > 0 
            then replace(regexp_substr(name, '[^,]+$'),']','')
       end
From your_table
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Not really. The result contains the closing `]` bracket as well (but it shouldn't).

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer. I thought that that OP gave bracket to represent the values.

Answer (score 0):

This option uses nested `regexp_substr`:

- inner returns substring between the last comma and `]` bracket. For example, for `[sundaar,j]`, it returns `,j]`
- outer returns a *word* between `,` and `]`

So:

```
SQL> with test (name) as
  2    (select '[pratik]'         from dual union all
  3     select '[Ishaan,llc,ltd]' from dual union all
  4     select '[sundaar,j]'      from dual union all
  5     select '[sid,h]'          from dual
  6    )
  7  select name,
  8    regexp_substr(regexp_substr(name, ',\w+]$'), '\w+') last_name
  9  from test;

NAME             LAST_NAME
---------------- --------------------
[pratik]
[Ishaan,llc,ltd] ltd
[sundaar,j]      j
[sid,h]          h

SQL>
```